# storing string in a vector has seg fault

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to read words from a file and store them into a vector, but indexing doesn't work. what's the reason making it keeps having seg fault? Why push_back() works? what's the mechanism differences between using indexing and push_back()?

```
vector<string> readWordToArray(string fileName, int wordCount){
    vector<string> wordArray;
    fstream inFile;
    inFile.open(fileName);
    string word;
    int index = 0;

    while(inFile >> word){
        // doesnt work, need to change to wordArray.push_back(word);
        wordArray[index] = word;   
        index++;
    }
    return wordArray;
}
```

Comment: Did you read the [`vector::push_back` documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/) and the [`vector::operator[]` documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator[]/) and notice the difference?

Answer (score 0):

`wordArray[index]` is for getting a reference to an *already existing* element in the vector, and I'm pretty sure it's undefined behaviour to use an index that's out of range.

To add one to the end, you need to use (as you point out in the code comments):

```
wordArray.push_back(word);
```

Comment: it need's Allocation

Comment: @sam, what are you talking about? This isn't Java. The vector and the input string are both constructed on the stack and do *not* need to be allocated.

Answer (score -2):

you should Allocate your Vector. vector.resize(int n) if you want to treat like an array. Otherwise you have to use Push_back() to allocate new memory at the end of your vector. look at the blow link for furthermore information [enter link description here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize)

Comment: If you want an array, C++ provides arrays. The problem with doing this is that you tie the size to the capacity. It's better to `push_back` so that the size always represents the number of elements in the collection.